# Facing AMQ4036 while connecting to Queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I am facing above error while connecting to queue manager. Let me first explain you what I'm doing.

I have created a new user on Linux machine(test) and then created a server connection channel(xystest.SVRCONN) with MCAUSER as test on XHUB queue manager.

Later i have granted access with the below commands.

```
setmqaut -m XHUB -t qmgr -p test +connect

setmqaut -m XHUB -n '**' -t q -p test +dsp +inq

setmqaut -m XHUB -n '**' -t channel -p test +dsp
```

When i try connecting to XHUB using the xystest.SVRCONN I am facing above error.

Can you please help me in understand where i have made mistake while allowing test user to access WMQ ?

Comment: At what version is the queue manager?

Comment: WMQ 7.0.1.10 version

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add +inq +dsp permissions for the queue manager too:

```
setmqaut -m XHUB -t qmgr -p test +connect +inq +dsp
```

Comment: I have ran above command still the same error.[bkradmin@ecllapmhubs651 LOCALHOST]$ setmqaut -m XHUB -t qmgr -p test +connect +inq +dsp
The setmqaut command completed successfully.
Done the refresh security but still the same AMQ4036 error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you are facing **authorization error**.

WebSphere MQ does not dynamically pick up new users or groups until queue manager been restarted or the Refresh Security of the queue manager. run MQSC command `runmqsc XHUB`  and do `REFRESH SECURITY`. *I hope you made sure, the newly created group is part of mqm group.*

Comment: The user doesn't need to be member of the mqm group, if you set correct permissions, and the permissions seem correct to me to allow connecting. The members of the mqm group have administrator permissions, which is not always good to give to every user.

Comment: Actually my new user is not part of mqm as when i add this user to mqm group then he'll have all the privileges which mqm has so i haven't added him to mqm group. I have tried granting him access using mqsetauth.           When i add this user to mqm group and revoke access with -alladm & -allmqi and tried put/get & clear it is still working for new user though the permissions are revoked.  Yes, I have restarted queue manager and i also did refresh security when ever i issue the setmqauth command.

Comment: "I hope you made sure, the newly created group is part of mqm group." What a bad, really bad idea.  Basically, you are saying give that group full access to EVERYTHING.

Comment: Hi Roger, My new user is not part of mqm group. here i'm trying to create a new user for one of my application and grant browse permissions only. So i have not added the new user to mqm group.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to refresh security is a valid one so if you have already done that, then try these tips for troubleshooting your authority error:

[Set MQSAUTHERRORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377578) to generate WMQ FDC file which will show the error.

Use the [MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg21299319) environment variable to create an entry in the QMGR error logs to show reason for security failures.

Once you have FDC and/or Log error to show why the authority is failing, you can determine what additional security you may need and then use setmqaut accordingly.